# Azure Storage Emulator fails to init with "The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist"

Tags: azure-storage, sql-server-express, azure-storage-emulator

I am having an issue with Azure Storage Emulator. I tried to re-initialise the database and got the error below.

This was after installing Visual Studio 2019 Preview but this may just be a co-incidence. I tried for an hour or so to get it running and then gave up and just  reset my machine with the "keep my files" option, re-installed Visual Studio 2017 and the Azure Tools but still see the same problem.

I know a reset sounds a bit drastic but VS 2019 broke my Azure Functions in VS2017, they would not launch so I wanted a clean install.

If I manually create the DB with sqllocaldb create (version 13.1.4001.0), the DB gets created fine but the init still fails with the same message.

Any ideas?

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage
>   Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init
>       Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.7.0.0 command line tool
>       Found SQL Instance (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB.
>       Creating database AzureStorageEmulatorDb57 on SQL instance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'.
>       Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist. Supply a valid database
>   name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..
>       One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again.
>       Error: Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist. Supply a valid
>   database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..

Comment: Have you tried to install the latest [v5.8 emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator)?

Comment: Yes, the 5.8 installer goes through fine but the problem remains.

Answer (score 61):

After resetting my machine (and keeping files), I ran into this issue. For me, I was unable to run an Azure function in Visual Studio 2019 due to an error around being unable to start the emulator.

It looks like I had the same permissions issues as (I presume) my new account after reset, did not have permission to touch the DB.

I resolved this by:

1. Deleting the Azure Storage Emulator DB file:  `%USERPROFILE%/AzureStorageEmulatorDb[number].mdf`
2. Then running `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start` with admin rights

I was then able to run the Azure Function without issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked, I deleted the .mdf file and rerun storage emulator START command. done

Comment: Yeah! This works for me, simply delete the mdf files and then run the ´init´ command again. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! That helped me also. I migrated to a new pc and accidentally copied this mdf file to the new pc so it prevented azure emulator from creating the db. Deleted it and it worked.

Comment: This worked for me, I have to vote this solution up

Answer (score 28):

1. Stop the Azure Emulator if it is running.
2. Open SSMS and connect to your (localdb) instance.
3. Manually create the "AzureStorageEmulatorDb57".
4. Open a command prompt as Administrator.
5. Run the "AzureStorageEmulator.exe init".
6. Run your VS project.

Answer (score 25):

I was running into this same issue after installing LocalDb for SQL Server 2017.  These steps helped me to resolve the problem I was facing:

- Open a command line in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator`
- Run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /forceCreate`
- From checking my error logs (located at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\MSSQLLocalDB`), I saw

> 2018-12-21 15:41:13.47 spid65      CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\Users{username}AzureStorageEmulatorDb59.mdf'.

- This error lead me to the following post: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191393/localdb-v14-creates-wrong-path-for-mdf-files
- From reading answers there, I gathered that this is a bug in SQL Server 2017.  Without having access to the patch, the solution that worked for me was granting `Everyone` access to modify `C:\Users`.  This was only an issue on my development laptop, so I could afford to make that security change
- or as commented by Andrii install [CU13 HotFix](https://sqlserverupdates.com/sql-server-2017-updates/) for SQL Server 2017. After that `AzureStorageEmulatorDb<xxx>.mdf` will be created you your user directory as it should.

Comment: Indeed this was the issue. 
I installed [CU13 HotFix](https://sqlserverupdates.com/sql-server-2017-updates/) for SQL Server 2017 and it works now.

Comment: Granting Everyone access to modify C:\Users solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Andrii this is much better solution (more secure), to problem described by this answer, big thanks. I've added that to `aleroy` answer.

Comment: this sequence work for me , stop->clear -> init-> start  
   https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/635#issuecomment-455845507

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem and I don't know why an **AzureStorageEmulatorDb57_log.ldf** was still present in my **%USERPROFILE%** directory when I deleted my MSSQLLocalDB instance, but after dropping that file the problem went away.

Comment: this worked for me but before doing this, i also installed SQL Express, so not sure which one fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

I came across this issue where I had changed the userlogin to my machine. I have created the database from my previous useraccount. I have copied the database files to the new user account but it gave me this error. It seems to be a permission issue.

You need to find the saved location of the mdf and ldf file of this database. In my case it was stored in 'C:\Users\yourUserName'

Simply delete these files and run AzureStorageEmulator.exe init again and it will create the new mdf and ldf files for you.

Comment: This resolved it for me too. Had the same error with both 2016 and 2019, and when I attempted to manually create the database using SSMS I finally got a useful error message (unable to create database due to file already existing) that pointed me to this solution. It's a shame the storage emulator was hiding that error message!

Answer (score 3):

After manually upgrading my MSSQL 2016 LocalDB to MSSQL 2019 following [these instructions](https://medium.com/cloudnimble/upgrade-visual-studio-2019s-localdb-to-sql-2019-da9da71c8ed6), I got the error mentioned as I was unaware that the Azure Storage Emulator uses LocalDB internally.

To fix it, I simply had to manually re-attach the database located in `%UserProfile%` with the following SQL command:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE [AzureStorageEmulatorDb510]
    ON (FILENAME = 'C:\Users\<username>\AzureStorageEmulatorDb510.mdf'),   
    (FILENAME = 'C:\Users\<username>\AzureStorageEmulatorDb510_log.ldf')   
    FOR ATTACH;
```

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

1. Delete any storage/sql database related to azure emulator
2. run this command on StorageEmulator path:

> AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server .

(Or your SQL instance, Mine was ".")

Answer (score 1):

This would probably not fit in the general case but for me I had to go into my Task Manager and stop the Azurite process. Then I went back into the directory and typed the start command:
`%\Azure\Storage Emulator\ AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`

this solved it for my case and wanted to share in case.

Answer (score 0):

Check you had install Azure SDK with Visual Studio, if you did't you can add the feature

[image: Error]

[image: No Error]

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the mdf and ldf files in your userprofile directory. Just stop the emulator and copy those files to some other place and delete it from userprofile directory.
Then run the emulator again and it's going to create new mdf and ldf files.
Then stop the emulator and copy the old files back and restart the emulator. This way you won't loose any data.

Answer (score 0):

I will help you with this. First of all create a sql server local db.
Then go to storage emulator folder
_-The Storage Emulator is installed by default to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator.

Then run this AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server

docs: AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server localhost\SQLEXPRESS01

Answer (score 0):

Open SSMS and connect to your (localdb) instance.
Manually create the "AzureStorageEmulatorDb...".

Answer (score 0):

To add yet another answer, I did not have the any MDF or LDF files. Instead, I only had a config file at `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\AzureStorageEmulator.5.10.config`. I also could not connect to my local `(localdb)` instance with SSMS.

I changed the `SQLInstance` value in that config file to be `localhost` rather than `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`, and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an app called Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator.

[image]

Start this application.

If the application indicates that it is running run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe stop` first otherwise run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe Start` directly. Should create your database automatically, at least it did for me.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because the mdf file already exists but LocalDB doesn't have it attached.  You can delete and recreate as others have mentioned, but in my case I was able to just re-attach it and it worked fine.

- Open SSMS to (localdb)\mssqllocaldb
- Right click Databases
- Choose Attach
- Click Add
- Select the existing MDF file (mine was in my user profile and named AzureStorageEmulatorDb510.mdf)
- Click Ok

Then try running the emulator again.

Answer (score -1):

I initialized the db instance and succeed, bu my SQLServer is 2017.

Then I search the solution and the [doc](http://www.hackered.co.uk/articles/azure-storage-emulator-init-cannot-create-database) said delete the trouble database will solve the problem. Maybe you can try it follow the steps in the doc.

Comment: I did try that and more. A fresh rebuild of my laptop solved it.

Answer (score -1):

This solution is **not recommended** in generally, but you can try it.
I think AzureStorageEmulator by somehow can not full access the localDB whitch setup in directory has limited the permission.

1. You can go to folder propertiy > sercurity > edit to full permission ( with me directory is user > Appdata).
2. Then restart the emulator
   [cmd restart the azure emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmHEu.jpg).

Now it worked. You must consider it's **unsercurity** later on.