# Azure Function BlobTrigger: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-trigger

I am not able to run my azure function locally written in java which should work based on BlobTrigger.

I am facing the following error:

```
 A host error has occurred
 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Net.Http: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. System.Private.CoreLib: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Here is my code:

```
public class Function {

    @FunctionName("BlobTrigger")
    @StorageAccount("reseaudiag")
    public void blobTrigger(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "content", path = "filer/{fileName}", dataType = "binary",
            connection = "AzureWebJobsDashboard"
                    ) byte[] content,
            @BindingName("fileName") String fileName,
            final ExecutionContext context
            ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java Blob trigger function processed a blob.\n Name: " + fileName + "\n Size: " + content.length + " Bytes");

    }
}
```

Based on initial run only, I can start implementing the logic but I am blocked to run the basic step itself.

Here is my local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=confidential;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "DataConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "ContainerName": "filer"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "PlantaoEntities": {
      "ConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=confidential;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
      "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is the local storage emulator running? You’ll need that if you want to use UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will remove this entry and try, because local storage emulator is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You need to specify a correct connection in your blob trigger.

Here is my successful sample:

```
package com.function;

import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;

public class Function {

    @FunctionName("BlobTrigger")
    public void run(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "trigger", path = "test/{fileName}", dataType = "binary", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") byte[] content,
            @BindingName("fileName") String fileName,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
                context.getLogger().info("Blob: " + fileName + " -> Length: " + content.length);
    }
}
```

I use the "AzureWebJobsStorage" connection in my code, so I need to set a connection string in the local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagetest789;AccountKey=*******w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java"
  }
}
```

Then, run the function locally and upload a file to the storage, I will get outputs as following:

[image]

---

**Note:**

1. When you publish your app to Azure Function App, the settings in your local setting file will not be updated to the cloud. You need to manually update them.
2. Please ensure that you have made your storage account accessible. If you enable firewall for your storage account, you need to add your client IP for local test, and allow trusted Microsoft Services to access your storage.

[image]

---

### Update

1. If you develop with VS Code, you can upload local settings from the command palette: F1 -> "Upload Local Settings"

[image]

2. You can also set application settings from Azure Portal
   [image]

And then you can modify settings here:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. In order to deploy the same to Azure, the host.json to have same entries? like "AzureWebJobsStorage", "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" only? Because I have successfully deployed it but I doubt if it is getting triggered upon Blob update.

Comment: No. The host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that affect all functions for a function app. For more information, please refer to:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: You need to update these entries in local.settings.json to function application settings in the cloud.

Comment: If you develop with VS Code, you can upload local settings from the command palette: F1 -> "Upload Local Settings"

Comment: The reason being I am asking this question is I am running it from jar file. But azure warning me saying it can't run from package. Using HttpTrigger it is easy beause I can use secure token to add it in the header while making http invocation. But here, it is not automatically triggered when Blob is updayed so it is dormant now.

Comment: @ARINDAMBANERJEE See my update. If you set the application settings correctly.  Your function app will be able to use the connection string .

Comment: These are ok as I used mvn azure-functions:deploy which takes all these properties. But function is not firing when BlobTrigers. I tried Kudu as well to upload the zip.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200597/discussion-between-arindam-banerjee-and-jack-jia).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it really took me almost 2 days to fix it.

This worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57757140/6688910

Basically, I had to delete the database located at %USERPROFILE%/AzureEmulatorStorageDb[Number]. Where AzureEmulatorStrageDb[somenumber] is the database it has generated.

Next, using cmd, navigate to Emulator folder

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator
```

Then initialize the emulator by running the following command

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /forceCreate
```

Now you should be able to run azure functions without any problems.

Comment: your first command needs quotes around the path fyi.