# Issue with Azure Storage emulator

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I installed the Azure Emulator on my machine. Then tried running the start batch but it failed with the following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator>AzureStorageEmulator.exe init Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.7.0.0 command line tool Found SQL Instance (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB. Creating database AzureStorageEmulatorDb57 on SQL instance '(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB'. Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases.. One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again. Error: Cannot create database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' : The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist. Supply a valid database name. To see available databases, use sys.databases..
```

I then created a database manually as suggested here: [Azure Storage Emulator fails to init with "The database 'AzureStorageEmulatorDb57' does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673763/azure-storage-emulator-fails-to-init-with-the-database-azurestorageemulatordb5)

It now starts successfully but it does nothing giving me this error in storage explorer:
Error Details
If you cannot resolve this issue on your own, you may open an issue on the Storage Explorer GitHub site. Please include the details below to help us diagnose your issue. Make sure to redact any personal information you do not wish to make public before posting.
{
"name": "RestError",

I am hoping it runs fine and I can create a table

Comment: Azure Storage Emulator is now deprecated and is not kept current with the latest changes in Storage REST API. Please use [`Azurite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) for local development.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Storage Emulator is now deprecated and is not kept current with the latest changes in Storage REST API. Please use [`Azurite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) for local development.

[image]